# SignalR - can only connect to server by IP address and not by hostname

Tags: c#, signalr

I have a C# SignalR server (running as a windows service under a domain account), which is self-hosting via OWIN and hosting an endpoint via http on port 9001.

It is using integrated windows authentication.

The problem is that my client can only connect to it using a URI that includes the IP address of the server. If I try to use the host name (either the short name or FQDN), the connection fails with a 401.

I ran a WireShark trace and see a 401 unauthorised in the working case followed by NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE and the usual handshake. In the failing case, I just get a 401 and it never moves on to negotiate.

Any ideas on what needs to be changed on either the client, server or on the host in order to get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: On your client side, how you call your hub connection? How you can access to /signalr/hubs?

Comment: Something like this (with Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client):

`var conn = new HubConnection(uri_value);
conn.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
var hub = conn.CreateHubProxy("myhubproxy");
conn.Start();`

Comment: Your ```uri_value``` is that takes the connection IP or hostname so I belive that you want to set it like ```document.location.origin``` or something like that?

Comment: uri_value is http://<host>:<port>

If <host> is the server IP address, it works.
If <host> is the netbios name for the server, or the FQDN, it does not work.

Comment: just make your host the current location and you will not need to worry about it again...

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what that means.

Comment: It means that in your client code, you can call the signalr HubConnection with not specified url.

Comment: But if you don't specify the uri, how will it find the hub on the signalR server?

Comment: Imagine this: you have your server development, QA server and production server. You will manualy add those url after you change the server? Or you can use a method that can get the current "location" and use it to the configuration?

Comment: I'm clearly missing something here - yes I can put the values in the config file, but it still doesn't change the problem: if I specify the server by IP address, it connects fine and if I specify it by hostname it does not connect. And yes, pinging the hostname does give the IP address! As stated in the original problem definition, the negotiation between client and server seems to be different (and fails) in the hostname case compared to the IP address case.